# Run Python file from matlab .m file

Tags: python, matlab, python-2.7, path, directory

I am looking to run a file I created in python from a matlab script. I have checked that my python file works if I run it from the python interface. However I have not been able to get my python to run from matlab. The following is the code situation I am in.

In matlab., I have the following code:(My file name is pgcode.py)
! python pgcode.py
and interchangeably I have use this code as well:
system('python pgcode.py')

The error that results in matlab is:
"python: can't open file 'pgcode.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

I have set my PATH directory and I really think this is an issue with setting the path so that I can find the file I have created but I haven't been able to figure out how to do this. I am using windows and Python 2.7.5. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There might be another way to do this, but here are two options.

First replace `system('python pgcode.py')` with `system('pgcode.py')`. Make sure that `pgcode.py` has execute permissions and in on your `PATH`. If you're using a unix/linux/mac type system, make sure `pgcode.py` has `#!/usr/bin/env python` as the first line, that's called a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29).

Option two, is to use the full path when you call `system(pathon /full/path/to/pgcode.py`).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your $PATH should control where python comes from, but I don't believe it will control where your pgcode.py comes from - at least, not in the way you're using it now.

You might want to either use a #!/usr/bin/env python and make your script executable, or be very mindful of what directory you're in when you try to python pgcode.py (you can prepend "pwd;" to your python command to see), or specify a full path to pgcode.py.

HTH